# Reasons not use Apache's error handler as a default mechanism?

Tags: php, web-applications, web

Typical web-applications call a default single server object (e.g. a PHP script) each time a request comes in.  In case Apache fails to find an applicable script or resource, Apache tries to deliver an error page.

Alternatively, one may design an web-app in such a way, that **no scripts or resources exist in the vHost's htdocs/root directory**. Thus, each request would force Apache to deliver an error page.

**If we define a server-side script as the standard error handler, any URL will trigger the script. Thus, the single script would be the single point of action.**

Is anybody aware of reasons, why this approach is wrong?

Comment: Close? What's wrong here? The question is a technical one. Isn't it?

Comment: I guess this is a best-practice question. I like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the page called by the ErrorHandler statement doesn't have access to form data such as $_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST, $_COOKIE (at least in my install of Apache/PHP).

After daring a journey into the pit of hell that is Apache mod_rewrite I eventually escaped with the following incantation, which seems to work for me:

```
<Directory /same/as/document/root/>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule /* index.php
</Directory>
```

The first line enables mod_rewrite.
The second line sets the rewrite base to the document root, i.e. so that URLs of all subdirectories are processed.
The third line sets a condition such that the rule is only activated if the requested filename ("%{REQUEST_FILENAME}") doesn't exists ("!-f").
The fourth line matches all paths starting with a "/" and redirects them to index.php.

Disclaimer: I know very, very, little about both Perl regular expressions and Apache mod_rewrite.

Just beware that the user may type in a URL path of the form:

```
 /some_directory/ or /some_directory
```

so you may have to handle both cases.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this is a penalty for the webserver.

Each time a resource is requested, it searches the filesystem for a file and if it doesn't find one, the error handler script is searched and run.

And if for some reason PHP fails, you do not get any error pages anymore and Apache will log something like an error occurred and another one while handling the error in the error handler.

Comment: It's faster to find whether a file exists or not and load a default object (that is probably cached) than loading a different, but existing file.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it, but you'd probably have to jump through some hoops to get the original URL, and to avoid sending HTTP error codes. If your goal is to use PHP for all requests, you'd probably be better off using [mod_rewrite](http://www.google.com/search?q=apache+mod_rewrite+php+all+requests).